# Neo4j - Howto delete duplicate relations based on their properties

Tags: neo4j, duplicates, cypher

I have nodes between which there exist multiple relations.
Each relation has two properties p1 and p2.
A relation is duplicate only when it has the same value for properties p1 and p2.

```
MATCH (a:Node)-[r1:Rel]->(b:Node)
MATCH (a:Node)-[r2:Rel]->(b:Node)
WHERE ((r1.p1 = r2.p1) AND (r1.p2 = r2.p2))
WITH a,b, TAIL(collect(r1)) AS coll
FOREACH (x in coll| DELETE x)
```

This does not produce the expected result.
The code above removes all, except the first relation.
Tail removes all except the first, which it seems to do. It does not take into account the properties however.
How can i delete duplicate relations and take into account their properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (a:Node)-[r:Rel]->(b:Node)
WITH a, b, r.p1 AS p1, r.p2 AS p2, COLLECT(r)[1..] AS unwanted
FOREACH(x IN unwanted | DELETE x)
```

For each pair of `Node`s, it uses [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) to collect all the relationships in the same direction having the same `p1` and `p2` values, and then deletes all but one.

*The `[1..]` list operation does essentially the same thing as the `TAIL` function.*

Comment: thanks !! this works...and it helped me to figure out the issue i had was related to a date being used in the properties, and which as formatted differently, and therefore not recognized in a simple string comparison ( dd/mm/yyyy <> dd/mm/yy).

Answer (score 1):

The matching logic looks right, I think your collect & tail code is where the problem lies. This works on a simple test graph I created:

```
MATCH (a:Node)-[r1:REL]->(b:Node), (a:Node)-[r2:REL]->(b:Node)
WHERE (r1.p1 = r2.p1 AND r1.p2 = r2.p2)
WITH collect(r2) AS rels
WHERE size(rels) > 1
UNWIND tail(rels) AS dupe
DELETE dupe
```

You could also make the matching more flexible by using the [properties](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-properties) function:

```
WHERE properties(r1) = properties(r2)
```

Comment: thanks !! this works...and it helped me to figure out the issue i had was related to a date being used in the properties, and which as formatted differently, and therefore not recognized in a simple string comparison ( dd/mm/yyyy <> dd/mm/yy).

Comment: The reason i didn't accept before is that i can only accept one of the two correct replies. When i have to accept only 1, I accepted the other reply because it uses less statements to produce the same correct result.